# OpenCV Split channels function may work improperly

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm stuck with this problem. I have a 3-channel image (cv_32fc3), and I would like to extract it into single channel. I use this below code to print the value of a specific pixel, but I got different results.
The first cout statement prints correctly with

```
-0.178382 0 0
```

However, the second cout statement prints

```
-4.31602e+008 -4.31602e+008 -4.31602e+008
```

And below is the code:

```
Vec3f pix = img_origin.at<float>(1464,487);
cout<<pix[0]<<"\t"<<pix[1]<<"\t"<<pix[2]<<"\n";
Mat channels[3];
split(img_origin, channels);
cout<<channels[0].at<float>(1465,488)<<"\t"<<channels[1].at<float>(1464,487)<<"\t"       <<channels[2].at<float>(1464,487)<<"\n";
```

I have search and read many examples and try many cases, but right now I'm lost in bugs. Please help, any suggestion is appreciated.

I thought this [Bug in OpenCV2.3 cv::split() function. Identical values in all 3 channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380829/bug-in-opencv2-3-cvsplit-function-identical-values-in-all-3-channels) relate to my question but it does not.

Comment: Vec3f pix = img_origin.at<float>(1464,487); // wait, that does not make any sense. (img_origin.at<Vec3f>(1464,487); would)

Comment: again, stick to the Mat's type for mat.at<something>()

Comment: You mean I need to cast channels[0] to Mat? How? About the Vec3f, am I using it correct? It gives me the correct value of pix[0]. But if I use Vec3f, I must do iteration and pass each value to another processing. I would like to use split function, but all the value it return -4.31602+008.

Comment: no, your first `Vec3f pix = img_origin.at<float>(1464,487);` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about reference. I just want to tell that I have search for related problem before I ask.

Comment: I'm confused. I use a software that can check value of pixel. And after checking, the Vec3f approach gave correct value. In addition, I think I'm using Split function wrong, it return -4.31602+008 for all pixels.

Comment: I have modified code into your suggestion, and it return -4.31602e+008. And now I know that is the way people get pixel values of channels. So what about Vec3f pix = img_origin.at<float>(1464,487);. What is it called? I would like to get that kind of values for all pixels.

Comment: Vec3f pix = img_origin.at<Vec3f>(1464,487); // and then, pix[0], pix[1], pix[2];