# How to use opencv::split(). Get crash

Tags: c++, opencv, std

How to use split() correctly? Why I get crash after doing splitting image to std::vector of channels?

```
cv::Mat imgOrig = cv::imread("cat.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> Ichannels;
    cv::split(ImgOrig, Ichannels); // have 3 channels here
} // crash here. When going out of scope
```

UPDATE:
std::vector Ichannels(3) fixes problem. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380829/bug-in-opencv2-3-cvsplit-function-identical-values-in-all-3-channels)
But I do not get how three channels share memory in my case. Values are different inside. Probably there should be sharing of some memory between imgOrig and channels.

Comment: Actually, `Ichannels` *does* have a separate copy (`cv::Mat` instance) of each channel. There is no ref-counting with `Ic`. In this sense, the `clone()` is not necessary.

Comment: The answer you are linking to refers to a different problem, the preventive creation of 3 empty elements in the vector is unnecessary. The code you have here, as long as the `imread` is successful, shouldn't crash, so the problem is elsewhere.

If you want to go deeper, if you check the code of split, you will see it prepares the output vector
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/split.dispatch.cpp#L231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::vector Ichannels(3); fixes crash

Comment: The preventive creation of 3 empty elements in the vector is unnecessary. The code in the question, as long as the `imread` is successful, shouldn't crash, so the problem is elsewhere.

If you want to go deeper, if you check the code of split, you will see it prepares the output vector
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/split.dispatch.cpp#L231